# remove all root element from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello everyone i'm new to json and am wondering how to remove all root element of json without knowing its name. Is there a way to remove the entire json root without knowing its name using javascript?

Json data I have:

```
{
  "ethbtc": {
    "name": "ETH/BTC",
    "base_unit": "eth",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  },
  "trstbtc": {
    "name": "TRST/BTC",
    "base_unit": "trst",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  }
}
```

JSON data I want

```
{
  {
    "name": "ETH/BTC",
    "base_unit": "eth",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "TRST/BTC",
    "base_unit": "trst",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks you

Comment: The final result isn’t valid.

Comment: @SumeshTG Can you give me a specific sample please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json={
  "ethbtc": {
    "name": "ETH/BTC",
    "base_unit": "eth",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  },
  "trstbtc": {
    "name": "TRST/BTC",
    "base_unit": "trst",
    "quote_unit": "btc",
    "low": "0.0",
    "high": "0.0",
    "last": "0.0",
    "open": "0.0",
    "volume": 0,
    "amount": "0.0",
    "sell": "0.0",
    "buy": "0.0"
  }
};
console.log(Object.values(json));
```

Use `Object.values`.to access all values from a json object without knowing the keyvalue.